# Python3: Urllib.request isn't working

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I put this into my code:

```
import urllib

print(urllib.request("http://www.google.com"))
input()
```

I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\Interwebz.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(urllib.request("http://www.google.com"))
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'
```

I have no idea what's wrong. I checked

```
C:/Users/David/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Lib/urllib
```

but I see nothing wrong with the files.

Request seems to not exist in urllib. (even though I found a request.py file in the urllib folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually say what you want to do but I assume you want to open a URL and read the response.

```
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.com") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a long explanation of this in their document, but let me make it short, its **init**.py is empty. so have to import particular module of it.
you were importing the library urllib and using its 'request' method, but for the case of urllib the import is like below.

```
import urllib.request
```

then it will work

all the method of urllib have to be imported like this and used.

other examples

```
import urllib.parse, urllib.error
```